# How do I resolve an "invalidMockError"?

Tags: postman

We are currently facing an issue wherein our postman collection is no longer responding with sample data created.  We have made no changes to the collection and have been using the collection as a way to architect our front-end application to an API contract.

Originally, this was working fine.  However, we are now being returned the following error:

```
    {
        "error": {
            "name": "inactiveMockError",
            "message": "Mock has been inactived due to an invalid                 
             environment. Please try to recreate your mock with the         
             desired collection and environment (optional)."
        }
    }
```

I've tried recreating the mock by duplicating the collection, but to no avail.  This error message is not referenced in the postman documentation.  Has anyone encountered this issue?  And has anyone found a solution that works?

Thank you, in advance.

Comment: Did you use an environment to create the mock? If the environment was deleted, the mock would have been deactivated.

If not, this is probably related to your individual account, and you'll need to contact Postman at help-at-getpostman-dot-com.

Answer (score 0):

The mock got de-activated because of the environment being used by it got deleted. You can create a new mock on that same collection and use the new mock url that is generated.